# Java Framework for Password Management

Tags: java, passwords

I am search java framework to manage passwords in my project like controlling password strength and encrypting password and any other features.

Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://download.java.net/jdk6/beta2/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html

http://www.bouncycastle.org/

http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/

(keyczar is the simplest)

cheers

daniel

Answer (score 0):

1. LDAP with the password extensions already does all this for you.
2. PrimeFaces comes with a visual password-strength indicator component.

Answer (score 0):

All these features included in this open source project but is is not a framework but an end user product.
http://www.mypasswords7.com/